# Python Logging - Override args/msg in "record" to avoid changing to mutable object data

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to implement the Python Logging filter with a redaction class in such a way that any call to log a message with arguments (eg LOGGER.debug('my message, %s, %s', data1, data2) uses a copy of the msg and args instead of the passed mutable object?   Our implementation means that the logging redaction class ends up changing the mutable data which then gets stored/sent with the redaction string.  I know we could do this on the call to the logger for example  LOGGER.debug('my message, %s, %s', copy.deepcopy(data1), copy.deepcopy(data2)), but was hoping there was possibly a way to override a filter function resposnbile for the "record" in the logging setup definition?

Comment: I can't imagine why `data1` or `data2` would be modified by anything in the `logging` module. Is there a custom handler, or formatter, or *something* involved?

Comment: This screams for a reproducible example.

Comment: We want to redact the sensitive data in the args/msg with a class.  This would change the mutable paramters.  instead for now we blat the entire line with "return False" as the solution offered below is failing us due to deepcopy not liking and object passed in under a certain logging event.

Comment: That doesn't require changing the parameters; it just requires constructing a log message using *some* of the available data.

Comment: As a simple example, if you only want to log the first 3 elements of a list, you use something like `msg = ' '.join(x[:3])`; you don't use `del x[3:]; msg = ' '.join(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the `makeRecord` function. By the time filters are applied the Record has already been created.

```py
import logging
import copy

class CopyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None, sinfo=None):
        args = copy.deepcopy(args) # <- this is the line you care about
        return super().makeRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)

logging.setLoggerClass(CopyLogger)
log = logging.getLogger('mylogger')

data1 = 'hello'
data2 = 'world'
log.warning('my message, %s, %s', data1, data2)
```